# Codeigniter not updating my data

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I'm new to codeigniter and developing a viewing catalogue website. And so far my update function isn't working and I've been at this for 3 hours

so here's my view:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('catalogPages/updateEvent'); ?>
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $events['event_id']; ?>">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Add 

      Title" value= "<?php echo $events['event_name']; ?>">
</div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Body</label>
  <textarea id="editor1" class="form-control" name="body" placeholder="Add 
  Body" value = "<?php echo $events['event_desc']; ?>"></textarea>
</div>

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

My Model:

```
public function editEvent()
    {   
        $data = array(
            'event_name' => $this->input->post('event_name'),
            'event_desc' => $this->input->post('event_desc'),
            'event_id' => $this->input->post('event_id')
        );

        $this->db->where('event_id', $this->input->post('event_id'));
        return $this->db->update('events', $data);
    }
```

Controller:

```
public function editEvent($id = NULL)
{
    $this->load->model('event_model');
    $data['events'] = $this->event_model->get_event($id);
    $this->load->view('adminEventUpdate', $data);
}

public function updateEvent()
{
    $this->load->model('event_model');
    //$id = $this->input->posts('event_id');
    $this->event_model->editEvent(); 
}
```

It works but so far when I try to update the data doesn't seem to be updated but rather doesn't change at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this Html form is submitted, the $_POST array has the keys:
'id', 'title', and 'body'.
There are no inputs named 'event_id', 'event_name', 'event_desc'.
The Html input properties 'name' need to change.